# Connect pixels in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

Please suggest how to connect the dotted pixels in an image like below:

[image: Test image][Original Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2S6R7.jpg)

I want to apply OCR on this image. I have tried some morphological operations such as thickening and bridging but not obtaining the correct output as expected (NH5343320).
The original image is also uploaded. On applying horizontal edge detection on the original image, I got the dotted image as above. Is there any another methods available for applying OCR in these kind of images.

Comment: What a priori information do you have? If you knew the width of characters ahead of time for instance, you could just identify the blobs within a rectangle from the top left point and connect the centers of those blobs with lines. then discard all the blobs connected this way and go to the next character

Comment: The image has gone through a poor thresholding. Can you also add the original image?

Comment: "not obtaining the correct output". Meaning? What is the correct output, what did you try and why it didnt work? we know it didnt get the correct output, you wouldt be asking here if it did.

Answer (score 1):

I would crop out and fill in a template for each of the available letters. Presumably, that would be the letters [A-Z] and the digits [0-9] like this.

**0.png**

[image]

**3.png**

[image]

Now I would do a sub-image search for each of them in your original image. I am doing this at the command-line with **ImageMagick** but you could use **Matlab**, **OpenCV**, or **CImg** or the Python, Perl, PHP, C, C++ bindings of **ImageMagick**.

So, I look for the `3` first:

```
compare -metric rmse -dissimilarity-threshold 1 -subimage-search plate.png 3.png result.png
25607.9 (0.390752) @ 498,46
```

So, the `3` is found at coordinates 498,46. There will be 2 output files, `output-0.png` which looks like this:

[image]

and `output-1.png` in which you can see the brightest areas showing where the match is best:

[image]

Likewise with the `0`:

```
compare -metric rmse -dissimilarity-threshold 1 -subimage-search plate.png 0.png result.png
31452.6 (0.479936) @ 664,44
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you explain how can we find the co-ordinates of the character to be searched. In your answer, you have given the co-ordinates 498,46 and 664,44. How can we find these points programmatically. Also can you please explain about the other numerical parameters used as I was not familiar with ImageMagick.

Comment: The coordinates of the top-left corner of the where the small letter template image matches the original image are given in the output after the `@` - I presume you can read them from there. The first number in the output corresponds to how good the match is. The dissimilarity threshold should be set to zero if you want a perfect match, or one if you are prepared to allow very poor matches and want to make your own decisions.

Comment: I guess you would use a normalised cross correlation in Matlab but I am not familiar with that product.